# How to save String value that I send from client to server?

Tags: java, android, json, jakarta-ee, heroku

I am making an android application that sends information from client to server. I am trying to send JSON object from client side to server side, but I don't know how to save it in the server side and then send it back again to the client side.

I am new to Heroku server and java ee, so I don't know how to code the server side.

Here is the client side code :

```
public class JsonHeroku {

public void executeGet()
{
    new JsonAsyncTask().execute();
}

class JsonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url;
            URLConnection urlConn;
            DataOutputStream printout;
            DataInputStream  input;
            url = new URL ("https://shrouded-lake-7996.herokuapp.com/json");
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setDoInput (true);
            urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
            urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
            urlConn.connect();
            //Create JSONObject here
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
            jsonParam.put("description", "Real");
            jsonParam.put("enable", "true");

            String str = jsonParam.toString();
            byte[] data=str.getBytes("UTF-8");

            // Send POST output.
            printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream ());
            printout.write(data);
            printout.flush ();
            printout.close ();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {

        System.out.println("DONE ----------------------------");
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

}

Now I must save it in the Heroku server :

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

port(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
staticFileLocation("/public");

get("/parse", (req, res) -> {

    // What do i write here?
  return "Hey baby";

});

get("/", (request, response) -> {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("message", "Hello World!");

        return new ModelAndView(attributes, "index.ftl");
    }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
  }

}
```

And if you can tell me how to respond it back to the client side would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save something on the server, you'll want to put it in a database. Here is an article on [Connecting to Relational Databases on Heroku with Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java).

Comment: Thank you, I read the docs and it was useful, But i think i will migrate my code to parse database because they accept json as parameters which will save me some work.